# Drag-and-Drop with pureJS and no backend

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a loader for jpg and png pictures and so far I've managed to make it work with choosing the files from the computer, but I can't understand how to make it work with drag-and-drop events. I would really appreciate if somebody could elaborate on this matter, please.

My current code is the following:

```js
var FILE_TYPES = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'];

var fileChooser = document.querySelector('.img-upload__input');
var preview = document.querySelector('.img__chosen-image');

fileChooser.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var file = fileChooser.files[0];
    var fileName = file.name.toLowerCase();

    var matches = FILE_TYPES.some(function (it) {
        return fileName.endsWith(it);
    });

    if (matches) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.addEventListener('load', function () {
            preview.src = reader.result;
        });

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
});
```

```css
.upload-img__field {
    position: relative;
    width: 685px;
    min-height: 405px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;

    border: 1px $light-silver dashed;

    @include tablet-large {
        width: 630px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 1100px){
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
}

.field__image {
    padding-top: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.field__heading {
    font-family: "Verdana";
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 29px;

}

.field__subheading {
    font-family: "Verdana";
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 27px;
}

.img-upload__label {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.img__chosen-image {
    position: absolute;
    height: 407px;
    width: auto;
}

.field__rules {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.field__size {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.field-grey {
    font-family: "Verdana";
    color: #9FAAB2;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="upload-img__field field">
                <img class="img__chosen-image" src="">
                <h2 class="field__heading">Перетащите файл</h2>
                <p class="field__subheading">Или <input type="file" id="upload-file" class="img-upload__input  visually-hidden" name="filename" required="">
                    <label for="upload-file" class="img-upload__label page-link">загрузите</label> его</p>
                <div class="field__rules">
                    <p class="field__size field-grey">
                        Рекомендуется 1600<sup>*</sup>1200&nbsp;px и&nbsp;выше, весом до&nbsp;10&nbsp;мб
                    </p>
                    <p class="field__format field-grey">
                        JPEG, PNG
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var droppedFiles = null;
 
 function fileContainerChangeFile(e) {
  document.getElementById('fileSelectBox').classList.remove( 'fileContainerDragOver' );
  try {
   droppedFiles = document.getElementById('fs').files;
   document.getElementById('fileName').textContent = droppedFiles[0].name;
  } catch (error) { ; }
  // you can also use the property from the fs field, but this won't work
  // with good old IE.
  try {
   aName = document.getElementById('fs').value;
   if (aName !== '') {
    document.getElementById('fileName').textContent = aName;
   }
  } catch (error) {
   ;
  }
 }
 
 function onDrop(e) {
  document.getElementById('fileSelectBox').classList.remove( 'fileContainerDragOver' );
  try {
   droppedFiles = e.dataTransfer.files;
   document.getElementById('fileName').textContent = droppedFiles[0].name;
  } catch (error) { ; }
 }

 function dragOver(e) {
  document.getElementById('fileSelectBox').classList.add( 'fileContainerDragOver' );
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
 }

 function leaveDrop(e) {
  document.getElementById('fileSelectBox').classList.remove( 'fileContainerDragOver' );
 }
```

```css
.fileContainer {
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
border: 2px dashed #dadada;
float: left;
padding: 2em;
}
.fileContainer [type=file] {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 999px;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
.fileContainerFileName {
width: 360px;
border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0.5em;
border-right: 0;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.fileContainerButton {
padding: 0.5em;
border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
float: right;
display: inline-block;
}
.fileContainerDragOver {
background-color: gold;
border: 2px solid #808080;
}
```

```html
<p>Select file to upload:</p>
<form method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label class="fileContainer" id="fileSelectBox" ondragover="dragOver(event)" ondragleave="leaveDrop(event)" ondrop="onDrop(event)">
<div class="fileContainerFileName" ondrop="onDrop(event)" id="fileName">Select File</div><span class="fileContainerButton">...</span>
<input name="fs" id="fs" onchange="fileContainerChangeFile(event)" type="file"/>
</label>
</form>
```

Hope this may help you in understanding the flow.

Comment: If it serves your problem. Please give it an accepted answer @MikeL.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you..

also can refer my fiddle here..

jQuery - https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/uk4p0L76/

Javascript - https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/bhp37rvu/

```js
(function() {
  function Init() {
    var fileSelect = document.getElementById("file-upload"),
      fileDrag = document.getElementById("file-drag"),
      submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-button");

    fileSelect.addEventListener("change", fileSelectHandler, false);

    // Is XHR2 available?
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xhr.upload) {
      // File Drop
      fileDrag.addEventListener("dragover", fileDragHover, false);
      fileDrag.addEventListener("dragleave", fileDragHover, false);
      fileDrag.addEventListener("drop", fileSelectHandler, false);
    }
  }

  function fileDragHover(e) {
    var fileDrag = document.getElementById("file-drag");

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    fileDrag.className =
      e.type === "dragover" ? "hover" : "modal-body file-upload";
  }

  function fileSelectHandler(e) {
    // Fetch FileList object
    var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

    // Cancel event and hover styling
    fileDragHover(e);

    // Process all File objects
    for (var i = 0, f;
      (f = files[i]); i++) {
      parseFile(f);
      uploadFile(f);
    }
  }

  function output(msg) {
    var m = document.getElementById("messages");
    m.innerHTML = msg;
  }

  function parseFile(file) {
    output(
      "<ul>" +
      "<li>Name: <strong>" +
      encodeURI(file.name) +
      "</strong></li>" +
      "<li>Type: <strong>" +
      file.type +
      "</strong></li>" +
      "<li>Size: <strong>" +
      (file.size / (1024 * 1024)).toFixed(2) +
      " MB</strong></li>" +
      "</ul>"
    );
  }

  function setProgressMaxValue(e) {
    var pBar = document.getElementById("file-progress");

    if (e.lengthComputable) {
      pBar.max = e.total;
    }
  }

  function updateFileProgress(e) {
    var pBar = document.getElementById("file-progress");

    if (e.lengthComputable) {
      pBar.value = e.loaded;
    }
  }

  function uploadFile(file) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
      fileInput = document.getElementById("class-roster-file"),
      pBar = document.getElementById("file-progress"),
      fileSizeLimit = 1024; // In MB
    if (xhr.upload) {
      // Check if file is less than x MB
      if (file.size <= fileSizeLimit * 1024 * 1024) {
        // Progress bar
        pBar.style.display = "inline";
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("loadstart", setProgressMaxValue, false);
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", updateFileProgress, false);

        // File received / failed
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            // Everything is good!
            // progress.className = (xhr.status == 200 ? "success" : "failure");
            // document.location.reload(true);
          }
        };

        // Start upload
        xhr.open("POST", document.getElementById("file-upload-form").action, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        xhr.send(file);
      } else {
        output("Please upload a smaller file (< " + fileSizeLimit + " MB).");
      }
    }
  }

  // Check for the various File API support.
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    Init();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("file-drag").style.display = "none";
  }
})();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.button {
  background: #005f95;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #4499c9;
}

.btn:active {
  background: #49ade5;
}

input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}

#file-drag {
  border: 2px dashed #555;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

#file-drag:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

#file-drag:hover,
#file-drag.hover {
  border-color: #3070a5;
  border-style: solid;
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 4px #888;
  color: #3070a5;
}

#file-progress {
  display: none;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#file-upload-btn {
  margin: auto;
}

#file-upload-btn:hover {
  background: #4499c9;
}

#file-upload-form {
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
}

progress {
  appearance: none;
  background: #eee;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
  height: 30px;
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( -45deg, transparent 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 66%, transparent 66%), -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #005f95, #07294d);
  background: linear-gradient( -45deg, transparent 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 66%, transparent 66%), linear-gradient(right, #005f95, #07294d);
  background-size: 60px 30px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

progress[value]::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( -45deg, transparent 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 66%, transparent 66%), -moz-linear-gradient(right, #005f95, #07294d);
  background: linear-gradient( -45deg, transparent 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 66%, transparent 66%), linear-gradient(right, #005f95, #07294d);
  background-size: 60px 30px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<form id="file-upload-form" action="">
  <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="fileUpload" />
  <label for="file-upload" id="file-drag">
  Select a file to upload
  <br />OR
  <br />Drag a file into this box
  
  <br /><br /><span id="file-upload-btn" class="button">Add a file</span>
 </label>

  <progress id="file-progress" value="0">
  <span>0</span>%
 </progress>

  <output for="file-upload" id="messages"></output>
</form>
```